# Why is the definition of subfunctor well-defined?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading the definition of subfunctor in a book and I disagree with it.  On Wikipedia I have the same definition:

> Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category, and let $F$ be a contravariant functor from $\mathbf{C}$ to the category of sets $\mathbf{Set}$. A contravariant functor $G$ from $\mathbf{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ is a subfunctor of $F$ if
>
> - For all objects $c$ of $\mathbf{C}$, $G(c) ⊆ F(c)$, and
> - For all arrows $f:c′→c$ of $\mathbf{C}$, $G(f)$ is the restriction of $F(f)$ to $G(c′)$.
>     This relation is often written as G ⊆ F.

Why does this restriction work?  The restriction $Gf$ to $Gc$ may lead to an image that is not a subset of the intended $Gc'$.

Let's say I take $\mathbf{C}$ to be the category with two objects $X$ and $Y$ and one arrow $a$ between them.
Then let's take the functor $P$ that maps $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$, $Y$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ to
$$x \mapsto (-1)^{x \;\mathrm{mod}\; 2} \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \right\rfloor$$

Let's take $Q$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are both send to $\mathbb{N}$.  Obviously, $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.  But $Q a$ restricted to $Q X$ doesn't work as $Q X = P X$ and $Pa$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

So should I discard $Q$ as a possible subfunctor, or should I discard $a$ and consider it to not be part of $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{C}(QX,QY)$ ?

Comment: You have not define the second functor in the first place, so you can't check whether it is a subfunctor yet. You need to define where it sends the arrow. But sure, as you see from this example, no choice will make this a subfunctor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Tobias commented, your mapping $Q$ is *not yet defined* on morphisms (i.e. you haven't specified $Qa$), so it is not a functor yet.

Actually, you are correct assuming that any subfunctor $G$ of a functor $F:C\to Set$ is determined by its object mapping -- since the subfunctor property exactly tells what to do on morphisms. 
However - as your example shows -, it is not true that any choice $\{Gx\}_{x\in Ob\,C}$ of subsets $Gx\subseteq Fx$ would determine a subfunctor.